# Error opening CA private key on Ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu, openssl, self-signed

I am trying to create a **self-signed certificate** using OpenSSL on **Ubuntu** 14.04. 
When I enter the command `openssl ca -in tempreq.pem -out server_crt.pem`, I get the following error:

```
Using configuration from /root/myCA/caconfig.cnf  
**Error opening CA private key** ~/myCA/private/cakey.pem  
139754719667872:error:02001002:system library:fopen:No such file or directory:bss_file.c:398:fopen('~/myCA/private/cakey.pem','r')  
139754719667872:error:20074002:BIO routines:FILE_CTRL:system lib:bss_file.c:400:  
unable to load CA private key
```

I have already verified that `nano ~/myCA/private/cakey.pem` command opens the `cakey.pem` file, and that the *read* permission for this file is enabled.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Ubuntu Stack Exchange](http://askubuntu.com/) would be a better place to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You seem to be running as root, check that you haven't accidentally followed the instructions on the ubuntu.com OpenSSL article too literally and set the dir param in /root/myCA/caconfig.cnf to /home/root/myCA.

This as the root home dir differs from all other home directories by residing in the top folder. So if you have set it to /home/root/myCA, that is not valid, you have to change it to /root/myCA.

**Edit (as this was the problem):**

Using "~" in the configuration might not work as it might not be expanded properly by openssl. If you are, try use absolute paths instead.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. Yes, I have taken this into account. I get this error while my dir parameter is /root/myCA.

Comment: Do you use the "~" in the config? That might not be expanded properly by openssl. If you do, try and use absolute paths instead.

Comment: I admit that I'm grasping for straws. :-)

Comment: Indeed, that was it... it has to be /root/myCA instead of ~/MyCA. Many thanks!

Comment: Ok, I'll add that to my response. Glad to help!